# R, glmnet: Cannot produce replicable results in cv.glmnet -- set.seed doesn't do it

Tags: r, machine-learning, random, glmnet

Every time I run `cv.glmnet` I get slightly different results (e.g., optimal lambda for model selection). Unlike most functions, `set.seed()` does not solve the problem. Does anyone know the cause of or solution to the problem?

Comment: Are you running this across multiple cores?

Comment: I'm running it on Mac OS X 10.7.5, which I think has a built-in multi-core facility called Grand Central Dispatch. Not really familiar with multiple core processes though.

Comment: I haven't used this function but it's not uncommon for cross-validation function run in parallel and I also know that setting seeds across multiple cores can be tricky (or at least not a default setting for many parallel packages). Needless to say, I'm no expert on this topic but if you can post your code an example of the results that would be helpful.

Comment: I was wondering if a solution was found for this